# How to make this validation work?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and I'm trying to make a simple validation of form.
I'm placing onblur event on a form and it doesn't work but it does work if event is placed on input itself. It would be great if someone can help me to solve this problem.

```js
function checkInfo() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value,
    email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    
  if(name === '' || email === '') {
    console.log('validate');
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

```html
<form method="post" name="myForm" id="my-form" onblur="checkInfo();">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name (Required)" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email (Required)" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="subj" placeholder="Subject">
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Describe your project in detail..."> </textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" id="my-form" onblur="checkInfo();">
```

to

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" id="my-form" onsubmit="return checkInfo()">
```

It should work. And you may also want to add an **action** attribute to the form, for example:

`<form method="post" action = "demo_form.asp" name="myForm" id="my-form" onsubmit="return checkInfo()">`

which means On submit, send the form-data to a file named "demo_form.asp (or demo_form.php etc)", to process the input.